# Is there any issue making HTTP AJAX calls from an HTTPS page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http, https

I know almost all browsers block HTTPS calls from non-secure pages, but what about the other way around? I am interested in using a free geolocation API that doesn't support HTTPS for the free plans.

Is there anything wrong with making non-secure AJAX calls from an HTTPS page? Will this produce any kind of browser errors?

Comment: Think about it: You want to access a potentially unsecure resource while you feel yourself being safe on a secure website...

Comment: If you currently have an https page you can add code to you can try to make an AJAX call to a website (any website) that doesn't use https and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

When you have mixed-security content on your page, it is dangerous, as that allows unsecured content to be tampered (which could then modify your secure content). For example, I could modify a script loaded over non-secure HTTP to do something nasty (like send all user data via AJAX) via a MITM attack. It's much harder to do this over HTTPS, as everything's encrypted.

Similarly, the content you send and receive from your AJAX request is transferred over a non-secure connection, so it could be tampered. Its danger depends on what you do with the response, but always use HTTPS when possible. It probably wouldn't matter if, say, you were getting the scores of a sports game **provided you properly escape and sanitise the data**, but if you were sending the username and password of an account, then...